# CakePHP browser emitting filename only

Tags: debugging, cakephp, browser, error-handling

I was asked to help out with a project that uses CakePHP. I know nothing about CakePHP.
The application was developed on a Linux platform, and I use Windows 10.
I installed and ran up the CakePHP 3.2 demo using IIS, it works.
I then started to install the project I'm supposed to help with.
I started to run into problems so I took a shortcut, I installed the bitnami WAMP environement and installed the CakePHP porect in that, it is using Version 2.8.
I have worked out a few issues, but I am not at a point where I am stumped.

When I run the application, the response emitted to the browser is simply a file name, that of the application, say, xyz.php.Nothing else and no log files or errors.

Would nayone have a suggestion as to where to start to figure this out?

Comment: I think you're better off asking such question in the CakePHP google group or the CakePHP IRC channel, as it's nothing that can be answered directly, it rather encourages a long back and forth. Without knowing the exact environment, and seeing the full source code, all people can do is shooting in the dark, which is anything but useful, and kinda offtopic on StackOverflow. That being said, I'd suggest to start with some debugging, add breakpoints and figure when/where exatly things start to go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The system I was working with came from a Linux machine and it makes use of Symbolic Links that do not migrate to Windows. The filenames that were emitted to the browser were the failed redirects of the Symbolic Links.
I received a list of the Symbolic Links from the originator and made Windows Symbolic Links, using, MKLINK.